# How to add map to message in protobuf3

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to create message with map that is supported since protobuf3. I cannot figure out how to add a map to message.

Proto file fragment:

```
message MyData {
    map<string, Queue> myMap = 1;

    message Queue {
        repeated float position = 1;
  }
}
```

Java fragment:

```
MyData.Builder dataBuilder = SnowflakeData.newBuilder();
dataBuilder. ???
```

I can get `dataBuilder.getMyMap()`, but i have problem with "set"

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`protoc` generates following method in the message's builder:

```
public Map<String, Queue> getMutableMyMap()`
```

It can be used to add elements to your field:

```
// ...
MyData.Builder dataBuilder = MyData.newBuilder();
Map<String, Queue> map = dataBuilder.getMutableMyMap();
map.put("key1", queue);
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#map-fields) is google's documentation for generated java code, section about map fields.

Answer (score 1):

use putAllxxx()

```
MyData.Builder dataBuilder = SnowflakeData.newBuilder();
dataBuilder.putAllMyMap(targetMap)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.getMutableXMap()` was deprecated. Instead you can use `.putX()`.